# Make an IFRAME scroll with entire page in elementor

Tags: html, iframe, scroll, elementor

I want to insert an iframe with HTML widget in elementor (wordpress) to serve as a background animation (the html inserted is a scroll based animation in threejs) but I don't know how to make the iframe to scroll with the entire page scrolling and to disable the scrollbar from iframe. I tried a lot of thing but without success.

Thank you!

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: If I insert <scrolling="no"> in css the iframe doesn't have scroll bar but doesn't scroll with body scrollbar. With <scrolling = yes> the iframe have a scroll bar.  With overflow = hidden the scrollbar doesn't disappear.

Comment: on which element you added this